# Error Cannot Implicitly convert type Generic IEnumerable to Generic List al hacer Union dos listas

Tags: c#

me pueden ayudar tengo dos listas las cuales una la  formo de desde un for y la otra desde un foreach y al momento de querer unir las dos listas me de ese error mi codigo:

```
 List<DtoLista> primeraLista = new List<DtoLista>();

 for (int i = 0; i < ConceptoIdentificacionPredial.Length; i++)
                {

                    nuevoconceptos.Add(new DtoLista
                    {
                        CODIGO = Convert.ToString(count1),
                        NOMBRE = ConceptoIdentificacion[i],
                        VALOR = ConceptoIdentificacionlBD[i]
                    });


                    count1 = count1 + 1;

                } }

segundo 

   var  segundalista= new List<DtoLista>();


            foreach ( var segundalistain form1.CONCEPTO)
            {
                conceptosAntiguos.Add(new DtoLista
                {
                    CODIGO=listConcepto.CODIGO_OTRAS_LISTAS,
                     NOMBRE = listConcepto.NOMBRE,
                    VALOR = listConcepto.VALOR

                });
                
            }

List<DtoConcepto> UnionConceptos = primeraLista.Union(segundalista);
```

Los datos vienen de otras listas que lleno pero no entiendo muy bien porque da ese error cuando intento hacer la union ya que son del mismo tipo DTO List porque se genera en un caso ienumerable y en otro una generica si alguien me puede explicar muchas gracias

Comment: Define List<DtoLista> segundaLista=new List<DtoLista>();

Comment: @jcHernande2 Muchas gracias , le puse eso pero de igual manera me sigue presentando ese error ienumerable to list

Comment: union te regresa un enumerable. IEnumerable<DtoConcepto> UnionConceptos = primeraLista.Union(segundalista);

Comment: o convertirlo a lista. List<DtoConcepto> UnionConceptos = primeraLista.Union(segundalista).toList();

Answer (score 1):

El resultado de un Union es una colección de tipo `IEnumerable<DtoLista>`, que es diferente a `List<DtoConcepto>`, por lo que debería ser algo así:

```
// Se usa ToList() para crear un listado a partir de un IEnumerable    
List<DtoLista> unionConceptos = primeraLista.Union(segundalista).ToList();
```

Si requieres que sea de tipo `DtoConcepto` debes transformarlo, puedes usar la función Select  para crear los objetos de tipo `DtoConcepto`:

```
List<DtoConcepto> unionConceptos = primeraLista
                                   .Union(segundalista)
                                   .Select(concepto => new DtoConcepto { 
                                        CODIGO = concepto.CODIGO
                                        NOMBRE = concepto.NOMBRE,
                                        VALOR = concepto.VALOR
                                    })
                                    .ToList();
```

Ahora, no estoy seguro si comprendes el objetivo de la función `Union`, me parece que lo que buscas es simplemente unir las dos listas, en ese caso deberías usar `Concat`.